# ruby recursive loop with sub-block return design

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, recursion

I have a Ruby application that I'm developing that, for some reason, does not work as expected when using a recursive function that contains a block inside to return a value from a different class' function call (easier to see in the example code below).  The odd thing is that when I created a minimal sample to try and find out what was going on, the sample works as expected.  Example:

```
require 'json'

class Simple
    attr_accessor :name, :children

    def initialize(name,children=nil)
        @name = name
        @children = children
    end
end

a = Simple.new('A')
b = Simple.new('B',[a])
c = Simple.new('C',[b])
d = Simple.new('D')
e = Simple.new('E',[d])
f = Simple.new('F')
g = Simple.new('G',[e,f])

foo = [c,e,g]

def looper(d)
    holder = nil

    d.each do |item|
        # puts item.name
        if item.name == 'D'
            holder = Simple.new('Z',[])
        elsif !item.children.nil?
            holder = looper(item.children)
        end
    end

    return holder
end

bar = looper(foo)
puts "Returned from looper: #{bar.name}"
```

In my actual code I ended up using the a class instance variable to get the response (which also works in the sample code).  Example snippet of the function from above modified to the other pattern:

```
def looper(d)
    holder = nil

    d.each do |item|
        # puts item.name
        if item.name == 'D'
            @holder = Simple.new('Z',[])
        elsif !item.children.nil?
            looper(item.children)
        end
    end

    @holder
end
```

So my question is, is it good practice to use the instance variable?  Any down sides to doing so since it works for my actual code whereas the first example pattern does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first piece of code, I'd expect to see a `nil` from your input, where in your second version you will get the object `Simple.new('Z',[])`

If that's your problem, it's because item `g` has children, the first one will set a value recusrively, but the second one will unset the value, so the second time through the loop, `holder` gets set to `nil`.

Edit: Actually my analysis of the results form the example above is *wrong*, because the last item in the top level list does contain the searched-for item. However, the analysis of the problem and difference in behaviour between the two solutions still holds in general.

You probably just want this:

```
def looper(d)
    holder = nil

    d.each do |item|
        # puts item.name
        if item.name == 'D'
            holder = Simple.new('Z',[])
            break
        elsif !item.children.nil?
            holder = looper(item.children)
            break if holder
        end
    end

    return holder
end
```

The break statement prevents you assigning again to `holder` . . .

Alternatively use Ruby internals like `#first` or `#any?` to express your search.

Assigning to instance variables as per your second example to inter-communicate between recursions is just fine, they are effectively shared state between all depths and iterations while the recursion runs. So it doesn't break recursion or Ruby per se, although you have to watch out for other kinds of unwanted interaction: For example you cannot assume an instance variable was set in a particular place during recursion, compared to current depth or loop item . . .

Comment: thanks for the response.  On my Windows 7, Ruby 1.9 installation, both versions return the same result.  Are you actually seeing differences or just expecting to?  This is one of the areas of Ruby that I find most confounding because what I see work in my simple example doesn't actually work in my full-fledged application :(

Comment: Actually you are right, I mis-read my IRB output, and the first example does return the object you want. However, the potential for it actually return `nil`, and my assertion for the need for break points is still valid - your two example pieces of code behave differently due to the possibility of `holder` to be set to `nil` after you have found a value, as you keep searching

Comment: A simpler way of putting my last comment - look at the value of looper( foo.reverse ) for your two variations of the function. You should see an example of what was going wrong in your production code, and a good example of why the best tests include variations of input data.

Comment: fortunately in my actual application there isn't the possibility of a child item having more than one parent (I made the example cover that scenario just to ensure it would behave)

Comment: Yes that should reduce the number of variations you need to test. You should look at `looper( foo.reverse )` though - reversing the outer array doesn't change any relationships between items, so it does represent a data variation you expect to see. And it exposes a difference between the two implementations of looper and helps to explain what is going wrong in the first version in your question

Comment: OH!  now I see what you're talking about.  I checked the reverse on the class instance version, but when I tried it on the original example I see the problem I'm getting in my actual code too.  Perfect!  Thanks for all the help; I've marked this the answer